# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error Error at XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, twilio

I'm using twilio client and when I disconnect the connection I get an error as following.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error Error
>       at XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYreadystatechange] (VM7676 twilio.js:55)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.H (VM7678 polyfills.js:3)
>       at t.invokeTask (VM7678 polyfills.js:3)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (VM7679 vendor.js:5425)
>       at t.invokeTask (VM7678 polyfills.js:3)
>       at r.runTask (VM7678 polyfills.js:3)
>       at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (VM7678 polyfills.js:3)
>       at p (VM7678 polyfills.js:2)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.v (VM7678 polyfills.js:2)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYreadystatechange] (VM7676 twilio.js:55)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.H (VM7678 polyfills.js:3)
>       at t.invokeTask (VM7678 polyfills.js:3)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (VM7679 vendor.js:5425)
>       at t.invokeTask (VM7678 polyfills.js:3)
>       at r.runTask (VM7678 polyfills.js:3)
>       at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (VM7678 polyfills.js:3)
>       at p (VM7678 polyfills.js:2)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.v (VM7678 polyfills.js:2)
>       at c (VM7678 polyfills.js:3)
>       at VM7678 polyfills.js:3
>       at VM7676 twilio.js:55
>       at XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYreadystatechange] (VM7676 twilio.js:55)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.H (VM7678 polyfills.js:3)
>       at t.invokeTask (VM7678 polyfills.js:3)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (VM7679 vendor.js:5425)
>       at t.invokeTask (VM7678 polyfills.js:3)
>       at r.runTask (VM7678 polyfills.js:3)
>       at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (VM7678 polyfills.js:3)

is there a way to debug it as I'm getting hard time in debugging it even a little help will be appreciated.

**Digging deeper:**
*I'm integrating streamtext along with twilio. I need to change the configurations of the streamtext so I need to change the url of iFrame for that. When I change the iframe url so streamtext iframe refreshes it all run fine but when I try to redirect back to some other page it's then that I get the above error.*

Comment: You can check for `network tab` of chrome, for requests & response.

Comment: I already have but no success I've updated that could be a problem but not sure about it

Comment: What Twilio library are you working with here in Ionic?

Comment: I have a plugin for my app but while testing I use twilio client javascript library to implement @philnash

Comment: Ah, I missed that you said Twilio Client at the start of the question. Sorry! So, to move on, can you share any of your code around this? It's hard to help debug with just the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I've still not been able to figure out what the problem could be but I fixed the error by instead of using property binding on iframe I switched to DOM manipulation.
What I did was

**Replaced**

```
<p *ngIf="state.state == 1 || state.state == 2">
    <iframe [src]="iframeUrl" id="transcribed-content" frameborder="0" *ngIf="iframeUrl"></iframe>
```

**With**

```
 <p id="iframeContainer" *ngIf="state.state == 1 || state.state == 2">

 </p>
```

And instead added iframe using this

```
  appendIframe () {
    console.log('onChange called')
    let elem = document.getElementById('iframeContainer');
    if(elem) {
        let iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.src = this.presentIframeUrl; 
        iframe.setAttribute('frameborder' , "0");
        iframe.setAttribute("id", "transcribed-content");
        elem.innerHTML = iframe.outerHTML;
    }
  }
```

So this error was gone with this.